# PreventDefault BACK Button

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, flex-mobile

Good day everyone, how could I prevent the default behavour of BACK Button for Android app in my Flex Application. When the menu is open I need close it by clicking BACK. For the second click i need to go the first view. The problem appears that when menu starts closing by clicking back at the same time it pushes to the first view and method preventDefualt does not work. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: you could try stopImmediatePropagation() or stopPropagation() instead of preventDefault(). Not saying it will def work, but worth a try

Answer (score 0):

Listen to the [backKeyPressed](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/View.html#event%3abackKeyPressed) event on the View.  In your event listener code you can close the menu manually, if it is open, or pop the view if it is closed.